# With Xen, is memory that's not allocated to dom0 or domU actually used for anything?

Tags: xen, hypervisor

The recommendations for Xen seem to be to set the amount of memory for dom0 to between 1GB to 4GB. But if after allocating memory to virtual guests we have memory "left over", is that actually used for anything?

If not, would it then be better to allocate the "left over" memory to dom0 so it can at least be used for file caching purposes?